# How do I view all editor tabs in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, ide, appcode

In Xcode 14 I often have a large number "editor tabs" open but only enough screen space available to see 4 about of them:

[image: only 4 xcode editor tabs visible]

Is there a way to get an overview of all active editor tabs, so I can quickly select the one I want to navigate to?

##### How AppCode meets this need

In AppCode I can accomplish this by via a simple dropdown:

[image: appcode dropdown]

An alternative option available in AppCode that would meet my needs is simply having the tabs wrap:

[image: appcode wrapped tabs]

##### My current workarounds

- I can use `command+shift+}` to move cycle through all tabs one-by-one, which is rather inefficient.
- I can use `comment+shift+o` to find the file by name, but if I knew all my files by name I wouldn't have much need for tabs in the first place. Recognizing a filename is much easier than generating it.
- I can hold click and hold the editor "back" button to see a list of all files I've recently visited. This is only helpful if the file I'm looking for was visited recently (and this would have to be *very* recently, as each file is listed multiple times, once per visit).

Finally, I'll note that Xcode has a shortcut to show all *window* tabs (`shift+command+\`), ie the old tabs tabs that existed prior to the introduction of editor tabs in Xcode 12. Unfortunately, no analogous shortcut seems to exist for editor tabs.

Comment: Great question. The only reason I use VS Code regularly is that I find Xcode tabs to be quite random (though smarter people than me say it's fine).